# Gradle CLI build fails on JarWriter from SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, build.gradle

**Error message:**

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
> > MALFORMED
>
> * Try:
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
>
> * Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.JarWriter.writeEntries(JarWriter.java:92)
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:144)
> ```

**Settings:**
*Java version:*
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

*build.gradle*

> ```
> import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
> import java.util.Date
>
> def profile = "PROD";
>
>
> buildscript {
>     ext {
>         springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE' //**have tried with 1.2.4 as well**
>     }
>     repositories {
>         mavenLocal()
>         mavenCentral()
>         maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
>         maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
>         maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
>     }
> }
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
> apply plugin: 'idea'
> apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
>
> mainClassName = "dk.api.gas.Gas"
> compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
> sourceCompatibility = 1.7
> targetCompatibility = 1.7
>
> compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
>
> jar {
>     baseName = 'quotes'
>     version =  '1.0.0'
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven {
>         url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot"
>     }
>     maven {url "http://xxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/artifactory/gradle/"
>         credentials {
>             username 'xx'
>             password 'xxxx'
>         }
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
>
>     compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
>     compile('dk.mobile:fileStorageLib:1.4.0')
>             {
>                 exclude module: 'dk.mobile:common'
>             }
>
>
>     compile('dk.mobile:common:2.0.0')
>     compile('dk.mobile:mail:1.0.5')
>
>     compile('dk.mobile:update:1.1.0')
>             {
>                 exclude module: 'dk.mobile:common'
>             }
>     compile('org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:3.1.0')
>
>
>     compile('dk.mobile:authentication:1.3.0')
>             {
>                 exclude module: 'dk.mobile:common'
>             }
>
>     compile('com.googlecode.charts4j:charts4j:1.3')
>
>     compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12')
> }
> def getDate() {
>     def date = new Date()
>     def formattedDate = date.format('dd.MM.yyy - HH:mm:ss')
>     return formattedDate
> }
>
>
>
> processResources {
>
>     filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: ["AppProfile": profile ]
>
>
> }
>
>
>
> task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
>     gradleVersion = '1.11'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when building on Windows. 
The issue was that I had files with long names so their path went over 256 chars and made the zipping crash and the bootRepackage fail.

On Linux on the other hand I didn't have any problem building the same application.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem might be that you have files with non ascii characters.

We hit the same error because of a few class names that used german umlauts (`ä`, `ö`, `ü`). After renaming the classes the problem went away (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building on Windows.The issue was the file named recources/statics/images/未命名.png,You can't use Chinese character.

Comment: It is an answer section my friend. I can understand your concern you don't have enough reputation to put comments but anyways we can't go over the policy. :(

Comment: what ghost,I can't understand your meaning.